# When are XIB outlet properties set?

Tags: ios, ios6, xib

I'm trying to implement inheritance with xib files. Yes, a little strange, but let me tell you why.

I have a class, SLBaseViewController that many of my view controllers inherit from. When I want a child view controller I create it in the usual way:

```
    SLHomeViewController *controller = [[SLHomeViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"SLHomeViewController" bundle:nil];
```

This works fine. SLHomeViewController is an SLBaseViewController (which is a UIViewController).

I'm doing this because I have other view controllers that I want to inherit SLBaseViewController behavior. In my case, I have a navigation UI widget that is common across my app, so a SLSceneViewControll inherits from SLBaseViewController also and both SLHomeViewController and SLSceneViewController both get the custom nav widget behavior.

The custom nav widget also has position information that is common across SLBaseViewControllers. So I implemented a poor man's way of doing xib inheritance.

```
@interface SLBaseViewController : UIViewController <SLNavBarViewControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *navBarExtendedFPO;
```

and the inheritance is done in initWithNibName

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        Class callingClass = [self class];
        Class slBaseViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString (SL_BASE_VC_CLASS_NAME);
        if (callingClass !=  slBaseViewControllerClass) {
            SLBaseViewController *controller = [[SLBaseViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"SLBaseViewController" bundle:nil];
            // now load all the properties by hand
            self.navBarExtendedFPO = controller.navBarExtendedFPO;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

If I create a SLHomeViewController is load the xib of a SLBaseViewController and then copies the interesting property from it. If initWithNibName detects it is loading a SLBaseViewController it just does nothing, preventing an infinite loop.

The problem is, of course, that the outlet properties are not set yet. So it just copies nil.

So when are these outlet properties set?

Or - is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? It all seemed rosy until I copy the properties by hand. That seems pretty brittle to me.

(Note, I'm fine with iOS6-only solutions.)

Comment: Ok so you have two `UIViewControllers` which inherit from a third `UIViewController`, correct? The problem here is that you want to use a small widget in all the `UIViewController's` + the `UIViewController's` XIB that you normally use from your subclasses? Is that it?

Comment: In view controllers there is lazy initialization. So, view will be loaded only after calling property controller.view - in viewController will be called loadView method and viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Yes Jacky Boy, except that there will likely be way more than 2.

Comment: How complex is your nav tool? Have you considered a method to generate it programmatically? something that could be called reflexively in each instance of your base view controller's subclass?

Comment: @PaulCezanne, sorry for my English, your IBOutlet will be not nil after you will call controller.view property :) just call controller.view before  self.navBarExtendedFPO = controller.navBarExtendedFPO;

Comment: No worries about your English, you speak more than one language, I only speak one. Yes, I just coded that up and it works. (I also needed to prevent some extra initialization in viewDidLoad but I used the same class trick as above.) Can you make your comment into an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because of UIViewController's the lazy initialization.

The view of UIViewController will be loaded only after some
one call the view property.

like that:

```
controller.view
```

So, in your case, you can just call `controller.view` before `self.navBarExtendedFPO = controller.navBarExtendedFPO;`

To explaining view life cycle more clear, there is an example:

there is overridden methods in your SLBaseViewController, `self.label` is analog
of `navBarExtendedFPO` defined in XIB file

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"initWithNibName: view loaded - %d , IBOuttlet loaded - %d", [self isViewLoaded], self.label != nil);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView {
    NSLog(@"loadView1: view loaded - %d , IBOuttlet loaded - %d", [self isViewLoaded], self.label != nil);
    [super loadView];
     NSLog(@"loadView2: view loaded - %d , IBOuttlet loaded - %d", [self isViewLoaded], self.label != nil);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad1: view loaded - %d , IBOuttlet loaded - %d", [self isViewLoaded], self.label != nil);
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad2: view loaded - %d , IBOuttlet loaded - %d", [self isViewLoaded], self.label != nil);
}
```

and there is method that creates SLBaseViewController

```
SLBaseViewController *testController = [[SLBaseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SLBaseViewController" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"after initialization: view loaded - %d , IBOuttlet loaded - %d", [testController isViewLoaded], testController.label != nil);
UIView * testView = testController.view;
NSLog(@"after calling testView.view: view loaded - %d , IBOuttlet loaded - %d", [testController isViewLoaded], testController.label != nil);
```

so, there is our logs:

```
initWithNibName: view loaded - 0 , IBOuttlet loaded - 0
after initialization: view loaded - 0 , IBOuttlet loaded - 0
loadView1: view loaded - 0 , IBOuttlet loaded - 0
loadView2: view loaded - 1 , IBOuttlet loaded - 1
viewDidLoad1: view loaded - 1 , IBOuttlet loaded - 1
viewDidLoad2: view loaded - 1 , IBOuttlet loaded - 1
after calling testView.view: view loaded - 1 , IBOuttlet loaded - 1
```