# Using a Mutable Array from another View Controller

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I've been looking around and found some answers but none of them worked, I don't know if i'm missing something. For some reason `punish.castigos` as well as playersView.players is nil at this moment in the code:

in GameViewController.m:

```
#import "SetPlayersViewController.h"
#import "SetPunishmentsViewController.h"

SetPlayersViewController *playersView = [[SetPlayersViewController alloc] init];
SetPunishmentViewController *Punish = [[SetPunishmentViewController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *punishments = Punish.castigos;
NSMutableArray *playersOn = playersView.players;
int pickCard = arc4random() % numCards;
int playr = arc4random() % [playersOn count];//here is where i get EXC_ARITHMETIC(code=EXC = i386 DIV..)
int punsh = arc4random() % [punishments count];
```

in SetPlayersViewController.h:

```
@interface SetPlayersViewController : UIViewController {
NSMutableArray *players;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *players;
```

in SetPlayersViewController.m:

```
@synthesize players;

//in view did load
players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",nil];
```

Comment: You instantiate `players` in `viewDidLoad`, chances are that the view isn't loaded when you access the mutable array. Just alloc/init the array in `initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951630/when-are-xib-outlet-properties-set/15956988#15956988 it describes sequence of calls in viewcontroleer, view controller life cycle

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of UIViewController's the lazy initialization.

The view of `UIViewController` will be loaded only after some one call the view property.
So, the `viewDidLoad` method will be called only after some one calls the view property too.

You should initialize your array in `init` method of view controller f.e.

Comment: wait so i'm kind of lost. What code do i have to add and where?

Comment: Have you made init method in your view controller? Put initialization of players array into that method

Comment: Read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html

Comment: The problem is that Punish.castigos in NSMutableArray *punishments = Punish.castigos; is nil, I dont understand what you want me to initialize in the init methods, Also i forgot to specify that the code in the GameViewController.h is a method that is called on the touch of a button, not on ViewDidLoad